# Google Action, Implicit Account linking DialogFlow webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, api-ai, google-voice-actions

We are planning to support voice action in our application to add user specific action. For example : If user says "Add milk" to google assistant, "milk" is going to added in application db on user account. For that, I have used Account linking(Implicit Flows) in Google Action as per this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow).

When i test dialog follow agent, i have enable "Sign-In" required checkbox for all intent including welcome intent. So that, when i invoke my application it will ask the user to sign in to link account to google.

I got the link account message and It has successfully linked. It says "Great! Your  account is now linked to Google" message.

Now, I have used webhook url to handle "add " intent. And intent is getting call our api as per the webhook. But when i print header in request, i couldn't see application Access Token, which is saved in Google. But as per the document (https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow#handle_data_access_requests) it will be available in header. But i cannot see access token in api request.

Why is the Bearer access token missing in request?

Answer (score 2):

That section gives generic information about the auth token. See the paragraph that says

> The specific method of attaching an access token to a request depends on the Google service that's calling your API. See the service's developer documentation for details.

The access token is available in the [User object](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppRequest#user) in the `accessToken` field. You can get the User object using the `conv.user` object if you're using the actions-on-google library and in the `User` environment attribute if you're using the multivocal library.